Searching for string in entire Pandas Dataframe including headers and all
I am really new in Python. While doing web crawling, there may be multiple dataframes crawled.
I need to use keyword to identify the right dataframe. Is there any way to search entire the dataframe including values and titles and everything?
I did try df.eq('apple') but it is still within values only. Please help, thank you.

If you crawl with read_html, use the parameter match: pd.read_html("your_path", match="apple")

You could check the columns, index, and values:
df = pd.DataFrame({'apple': ['a', 'b', 'c']}, index=['x', 'y', 'z'])

def df_contains(df, target, exact=True):
    if exact:
        return (target in df) or (target in df.index) or df.eq(target).any().any()
    return (df.columns.str.contains(target).any() or
            df.index.str.contains(target).any() or
            df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains(target).any()).any()
           )

df_contains(df, 'apple') # True
df_contains(df, 'ppl') # False
df_contains(df, 'ppl', exact=False) # True

A shorter alternative could be to convert to_csv as string (assuming the string wouldn't get escaped!):
'apple' in df.to_csv()  # True
'ppl' in df.to_csv()  # True

Note that this would also consider substrings.

super thanks @mozway. In my tries, it works with whole string but does not work with substrings containing.

@navafolk see update

You can use df.stack() to stack the columns into rows.
data = {
    'Product': ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana'],
    'Price': [1.5, 2.0, 0.5]
}
keyword = 'apple'
stacked_df = df.stack()

matches = stacked_df[stacked_df.str.contains(keyword, case=False, na=False)]

Output
0  Product    Apple

